# Prism for .NET 3.5 and EntLib 5 (or Unity 2)

Tags: .net, prism, enterprise-library

is it possible to develop with Prism under .NET 3.5 using EntLib 5? According to documentation, Prism 2.1 targets .NET 3.5, but it works with EntLib 4. And Prism 4 works with EntLib 5, but in requirements section of documentation said that .NET 4 is required. The question is: can I develop with Prism using EntLib 5? I already use EntLib 5, and I don't want to include EntLib 4 assemblies either. I also can't use .NET 4 due to my employer's limitations.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read [here](http://entlib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EntLib5ReleaseNotes&referringTitle=EntLib5), EntLib 5 does have support for .Net 3.5 SP1. As you said Prism v4 targets .Net 4.0 (and uses some of its features heavily), so that version is probably not the way to go.

I would just include the necessary EntLib 5.0 assemblies in Prism (I don't think there are many dependencies other than Unity) and build the Prism code. Then you can just use [Prism 2.2](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/46046) with EntLib 5.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
Damian